# How to load a part of store into a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

**Ext JS 5.1**

I have a student management system, and 4 classes from 1th to 4th. All classes have 4 courses each. I called all courses to grid but I want to call only courses that have same class with the student. (e.g I'm on 4th class so I can see only 4th class courses on grid)

**I just want to part of code like this if it is possible:**

```
    if (refs.txtClass.value === refs.lesClass.value){

       // load the grid that only equals txtClass.value
       // txtClass is Class No of a student, lesClass is Class No of grid

    }
```

**Student's Class Reference**

```
items: [{
         xtype: 'label',
         flex: 1,
         reference: 'txtClass'
        }]
```

**Grid Code**

```
items: [
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    flex: 1,
    reference: 'courseList',
    itemId: 'courseList',
    store: 'CourseStore',
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            reference: 'lesId',
            itemId: 'lesId',
            dataIndex: 'lesId',
            text: 'DERS KODU'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            reference: 'lesClass',
            itemId: 'lesClass',
            dataIndex: 'lesClass',
            text: 'SINIF'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            reference: 'lesName',
            itemId: 'lesName',
            width: 200,
            dataIndex: 'lesName',
            text: 'DERS ADI'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            reference: 'lesCredit',
            itemId: 'lesCredit',
            dataIndex: 'lesCredit',
            text: 'DERS KREDİSİ'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            reference: 'lesTeacher',
            itemId: 'lesTeacher',
            width: 600,
            dataIndex: 'lesTeacher',
            text: 'OKUTMAN'
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: The short answer is, it depends. Do you already have the data loaded and want to filter it locally? Or do you want to load only those items from the server?

Comment: I loaded from local, no server yet @EvanTrimboli

Answer (score 2):

If you have loaded all data locally , you can then filter on store based on the condition.

> **filterBy ( fn , [scope] )** 
>   Filters by a function. The specified function will be called for each Record in this Store. If the function returns true the Record is included, otherwise it is filtered out.
>   When store is filtered, most of the methods for accessing store data will be working only within the set of filtered records. The notable exception is getById.

```
store.filterBy(function() 
{
if (refs.txtClass.value === refs.lesClass.value){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
},this);
```

You can also make use of filters config on the store.

```
 filters: [
    function(item) {
        //condition here
    }
]
```

Comment: hello, first should i add this page's afterrender? when i did, giving me "store is not defined". Or "Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("CourseStore").filterBy(this, function().." is also not working. I called the datas from Store with using dataIndex, that is right isnt that?

Comment: You can do this afterrender also. You can get the grid reference like grid.getStore();

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also loadData method of store to load some part of data in store :
    var arr = [],
    store = yourgrid.getStore();
    store.each(function(rec) {
    if (// condition to create the part of data want to be loaded)){
        arr.push(rec);
    }
    store.loadData(arr);
```

You can also used slice method to store some data on the basis of range 
   store.loadData(oldstoreRecords.slice(start,end);